# How to change the font in RIDE for Dyalog APL?

Tags: apl, dyalog, dyalog-ride

There are many [APL Fonts](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Fonts) I am interested in using with the [Remote IDE for Dyalog APL](https://github.com/Dyalog/ride).

How do I change the font in RIDE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RIDE is essentially a Chromium web browser and fonts are controlled by CSS.
so if you could find the CSS file `style/ride-base.css` in your installation (for example `/Applications/Dyalog.app/Contents/Resources/Dyalog/RIDEapp/style` on macOS), you can modify the [line that defines `apl` font family](https://github.com/Dyalog/ride/blob/238af6e3ed6ed3d653728cf517c7868c5dbaf7a6/style/ride-base.css#L37) to the font that you desire.

Or you can `F12` in RIDE to open the web inspector to test out the font on the fly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am on macOS and the location of the correct CSS file to edit was `/Applications/Dyalog-18.2.app/Contents/Resources/app/style`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `<CTRL>+<+>` and `<CTRL>-<->` to increase/descrease the font size.